# How to pass data from one function to another in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a React project, I'am able to pass data from submit button to common function but, I want to pass data from radio button to common function. See for reference below

1. App.js

```
/* The function where the query is extracted from another function */

/* Common Function -> getData */
const getData = async () => {
    
    /* I get query value from onSubmit and not from handleChange */
    console.log('QUERY', query)
    if (query !== "") {
      const result = await Axios.get(url);
      
      console.log(result)
      if (!result.data.more) {
        return toast.error('No such food', {
          autoClose: 2000
        }, setQuery(""))
      }
      setRecipes(result.data.hits);
      setQuery("");
    } else {
      toast.error('Please Fill the form', {
        autoClose: 2000
      })
    }
  };

/* I get value fom this function */
const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    getData();
  };

  const onChange = e => 
  {
      setQuery(e.target.value);
  }

   /* I want value from this function to pass to getData() */
   const handleChange = e => {
    console.log('VALUE', e.target.value)
    setQuery(e.target.value);
    getData(e)
  }

      {/* Search Button */}
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="search-form">
       <input
         type="text"
         name="query"
         onChange={onChange}
         value={query}
         autoComplete="off"
         placeholder="Search Food"
       />
       <input type="submit" value="Search" />
       <br/>
     </form>

    {/* Radio Button */}
    <ButtonGroup toggle style={{width:'100%'}}>
        {radios.map((radio, idx) => (
          <ToggleButton
            key={idx}
            type="radio"
            active="true"
            variant="light"
            name="radio"
            value={radio.value}
            checked={radioValue === radio.value}
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleChange(e);
              setRadioValue(e.currentTarget.value);
            }}
            size="lg"
          >
            {radio.name}
          </ToggleButton>
        ))}
      </ButtonGroup>
```

Thus, I'am unable to get query value from handleChange for Radio Button. No value is shown for handleChange, whereas with onSubmit I do get query value. What could be the better solution to tackle this problem?

Comment: `e.target` will be different for both events, when you select the Radio button are you still trying to read the value of the `query` input?

Comment: Hi thanks for response... When clicked on Radio button I'am getting value but, I want it to pass to getData() which is possible with onSubmit() function

Comment: So you get the correct value but you are saying when you call `getData` inside your `handleChange` it doesn't pass the value to `getData`?

Comment: Yes perfect... You got it

Answer (score 0):

I would use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for this. It can be used with a class or functions.

Something like this:

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    state = { query: '', recipes: null }
    url:string;
    render() { }
    handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log('VALUE', e.target.value);
        this.setQuery(e.target.value);
        this.getData(e)
    }

    setQuery = (query) => this.setState({ ...this.state, query });
    getData = async (e) => {
        const { query } = this.state;
        if (query !== "") {
            const result = await Axios.get(this.url);
            /** same logic is here */

            this.setState({ ...this.state, recipes: result.data.hits })
        }
    }
}
```

Main benefit of this is the automatic rendering of the element, whenever the state changes. So you will always see actual data on the View.

If you are using React 16.8 and prefer to use functions, you might use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

With hooks it will be something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
export default () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState('');

    const setMyQuery = (v: any) => {
        console.log(v);
        setQuery(v)
    }

    const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        console.log('VALUE', e.target.value);
        setMyQuery(e.target.value);
        getData(e)
    }

    const getData = async (_: any) => {

        if (query !== "") {
            const result = await Promise.resolve('result')
            /** same logic is here */
            setRecipes(result)
        }
    }

    return (<div>
        {recipes}
        {query}
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible with function component of React?

Comment: If you are using react ```React 16.8``` - yes. Hooks was introduced for this purpose. I will update the post

Comment: My intention was to pass data from handleChange to getData so that I can get output

Comment: You need to store data somewhere. And you need to know to React that data was changed.  State was designed exactly for this.

Comment: I did as per your code but, still error persists that 'No such food'... That is query consoled in getData() is null

Comment: It can be null, if you put null there :) If you are using the first approach, change it to: 
``` setQuery = (query) =>{console.log(query);  this.setState({ ...this.state, query });} ``` If second, wrap the setQuery with you own  function and do the same. I assume the issue is with event value. Cause after init, query should be an empty string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218608/discussion-between-pranav-and-drag13).

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the same event target for both these scenarios e.g. for `<input name="query"...` it's fine to use `target` because we know we are explicitly interacting with that element.

On the `ToggleButton` scenario, the event isn't initiated by the underlying `input` field therefore `target` & `currentTarget` will differ. To be consistent, you can either use `e.currentTarget.value` for both scenarios or you can use `e.currentTarget` for the Radio button and `e.target` for the query input.

Comment: Now query value I'am getting in console in getData() method, but, output is not reflected

Comment: @Pranav if the value is there then the question has been answered :) the results part is outwith the scope, you'll need to look at your server-side to understand why the API call doesn't return the results you expect